# Case insensitive for part of the regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex where part of the regex should be case insensitive.

Example:

```
/Guest post by ([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)/
```

"Guest post by" should be case insensitive, but the 2nd half obviously needs to be case sensitive as it's looking for a first name + last name, with the first letter capitalized in each.

So if I do

```
/Guest post by ([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)/i
```

it won't work because now it'll match things such as "Guest post by small dog", which I don't want.

However, it needs to match with "GUEST POST BY Brian Williams".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the case-insensitive modifier pattern:

```
(?i:)
```

In your case:

```
(?i:Guest post by )([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/pW1gV9

Alternatively (thanks @robertodecumex!) you can use a modifier range, which is handy if you want to exclude the result from capture.

```
(?i)Guest post by(?-i) ([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+)
```

Comment: or you can do that :P Much better +1

Comment: there was an example with ranges too. http://regex101.com/r/vH3dF5 Adding that may be useful.

Comment: @robertodecurnex for sure - if you need that, though I could see that mostly being handy if you're using capture groups (and not wanting to capture that section).

Comment: Sure, just thinking about the people that may come here in the future googling for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Regexp composition like this

```
/#{/guest post by/i} #{/[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]/}/
```